# Missing host to link to Rails heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I have an app that I am trying to put onto production. When the user signs up they have an activation email that should be sent to their email accounts but I am getting stopped with this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error(Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true)
```

The problem with this error is that I have everything set up correctly in my files. For example my production.rb file inside my environments folder looks like this:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'secret-everglades-54128.heroku.com'}
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

My enviorments.rb file looks like this:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'secret-everglades-54128.heroku.com'}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

This does not make any sense to me whatsoever, if anyone could shed some light on this problem I will be very great full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had errors still concuring when I ran the command

```
 git push heroku master
```

The problem was that I had my host set in the actually environment.rb file which wasn't needed so I removed that and once I did that I was able to get everything to work.